# Let user know if there's a pending edit from the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review

I was trying to edit an answer from the review queue (late answers), and nothing happened - like the `edit` button/link is not working.

So I entered the post page, and then when trying to edit I got the message that there's already a pending edit for that post, so I can't submit another edit.

Is it possible to add this red message also to the reviews page, when trying to edit and it's not possible?

[image]

P.S. I'm not sure if this kind of things should be here or at the [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Seems like a feature request rather than a bug report. Regardless, yes, this sort of thing is okay here. Supposedly, the devs monitor [meta-tag:bug] and [meta-tag:feature-request] on all per-site metas.

Comment: OK, so good to know it fits here - should I change the tag to feature-request?